# Yii2: How to progress Step Progress bar in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

Trying to implement **Auto Increment Step Progress Bar** using jquery.

[image]

**Table where my data will be displayed-**

```
<table class="table" align="center">            
<tr>
<td>Job Code</td>
<td><b><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->job_code; ?></b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Client Code</td>
<td><b><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->client_code; ?></b></td>
 </tr>
<tr>
<td>Status</td>
<td id="status"><b><span class="label label-success"><?php echo ' ' . $dataProvider->models[0]->status; ?></b></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**JS -**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var i = 1;
$('.progress .circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
setInterval(function() {
$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + i + ')').addClass('active');

$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

$('.progress .circle:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ') .label').html('&#10003;');

$('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 1) + ')').addClass('active');

$('.progress .bar:nth-of-type(' + (i - 2) + ')').removeClass('active').addClass('done');

i++;

if (i == 0) {
$('.progress .bar').removeClass().addClass('bar');
$('.progress div.circle').removeClass().addClass('circle');
i = 1;
}
}, 1000);
});
```

I have given table field an Id, I want to progress this bar like-

```
if(status=approved)
{
  progress up to one step
}
elseif(status==digital)
{
progress up to Digital
}
elseif(status==CDP)
{
progress up to CDP
}
elseif(status==Printing)
{
progress up to Printing
}
and so on...
```

script should get value from table field and progress and step bar up to appropriate status. 
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

TO do similar, you can use **[Twitter Bootstrap Wizard Plugin](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/#)** It is easy to use plugin, you don't need to do multiple if condition and jQuery code for wizard. You can see **[demo Here](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-pills.html#)**

You can user your css style instead of first, second,etc text in the **[demo](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/examples/basic-pills.html#)**.

Comment: in this we have to click button to get bar in next step, i need auto increment, how to do that?